# Shopify: Display discount codes in new order email template

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to display discount codes in new order email notification template, using this code:

```
{% for discount in discounts %}
  {{ discount.code }} : {{ discount.savings | money_with_currency }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's displaying the discount amount but not the discount code name/title. It's returning blank even if the discount is manually entered in the back-end when creating an order.

How can I display discount codes no matter where it's entered i.e in admin or checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notifications you may access to discount_application object as explained here:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/discount-application

So (not tested), something like that might work:

```
{% for discount_application in discount_applications %}
  {{ discount_application.title }} : {{ discount_application.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

HTH

Comment: Above worked, but by just accessing discount_applications. No need to reference order.discount_applications

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from your cookies:

```html
  <div id="discount-message"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var codeCookieValue;
    var getCookie = function(name) {
      var value = "; " + document.cookie;
      var parts = value.split('; '+name+'=');
      if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    };
    codeCookieValue = getCookie('discount_code');
  </script>
```